# How can I reassign F5 in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, customization

Can I make it so that F5 doesn't "run" in VS any more? I'm too used to running queries in SSMS and then moving to VS and running my project when I'm not ready.

A case of Premature Execution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to Tools|Options, then select Keyboard under the Environment tree. In the listbox in the window, locate the Debug.Start command - you should see that it is mapped to the F5 key.

Click the Remove button to unmap the key.

Comment: Thanks. Got the Accept for the 'Remove' bit.

Answer (score 8):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> keyboard

then below "Show commands containing" label type 'debug.start' w/o quotes

Answer (score 0):

This will disable F5 for EVERYTHING in visual studio, which is what the the OP requested. However, for people (like me) that have their feet in both the T-SQL world and in C#, F5 can't be disabled for everything. Here's how to disable F5 for just the SSRS projects.

[How do NOT deploy a SQL Server Database project when debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866397/how-do-not-deploy-a-sql-server-database-project-when-debugging)

Comment: Please note that the essential parts of the answer here should be posted on this site [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). 
You might include the link  as a reference.