# How do NOT deploy a SQL Server Database project when debugging?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 11 Beta with a SQL Server Database project and a console app project.  Every time I hit F5 to debug my console app, it wants to deploy the database project. Is there any way to keep it from doing that? I can't find any settings to prevent it.

Answer (score 40):

The problem here is that when you say *I want to build and deploy* (hitting F5 does this in order to debug) you don't actually want the DB to be part of that deployment.

I'm afraid I don't have VS 11 Beta, but this is  achieved by disabling the Deploy of the project in the Build Configuration.

Below is a screenshot from VS 2010, hopefully you can find an equivalent (sorry, I couldn't find the MS documentation for 2012).

Find the project you don't want to deploy, and uncheck the relevant check box under the Deploy column.

[image: Where to find the Build Configuration drop down]

[image: Select Configuration Manager from the drop down]

[image: Uncheck Deploy for the relevant project]

Comment: It depends on what the OP meant, but if he did not want *any* deployment actions to occur (including generating a SQL script, in the case of the accepted answer above), this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Double-click on the Properties node of the Database project in Solution Explorer to open the Database project properties. Select the Deploy tab. In the Deploy action section, select "Create a deployment script (.sql)" instead of "Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database".

Comment: The Deploy tab is not present in VS 11 Beta. There is a "Create Script" checkbox on the Project Settings tab, but checking this still results in the database being deployed. Any more clues?

Comment: If no deployment actions should be taken, it should be disabled in the Configuration Manager. See other answer.